# C# Windows Forms Timer

Tags: c#

I need some code to run every few seconds. Without using Simultaneous programming, how can I achieve this?

I tried Simultaneous programming but this means that I can't pass variables between the two separately running processes.

Comment: What's the problem with System.Windows.Forms.Timer?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: When you say "Without using Simultaneous programming" I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to go without.  Do you just mean without starting a second process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Timer` component to execute code periodically.

For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create a timer and set its interval in milliseconds
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000; // Change this value to set the interval (in milliseconds)
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Start the timer when the form loads
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code to be executed periodically
        MessageBox.Show("Timer ticked!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a timer in the form designer. It will create a method that runs for every second.

`private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {// Code here}`

Your method should look something like this.